# Best way to emulate __typeof__ for msvc or alternative workaround?

Tags: c, overloading, typeof, visual-studio-2012, printf-debugging

I have some [code](https://github.com/rtaycher/debug_print_h/blob/master/debug_print.h)

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT(x,...) \
    do \
    {\
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wunused-value\"") \
        __typeof__((0,x)) _x = x; \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop") \
        DEBUG_PRINT_PTR((#x), &_x, __VA_ARGS__);\
    } while(0)


//The repetition of debug_print_printf_specifier is to avoid repetition for custom types.
#define DEBUG_PRINT_PTR(xstr, xp,...) \
_Generic((*xp), \
const char *: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
char *: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
int: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
float: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
double: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
char: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
int16_t: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
uint16_t: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
uint32_t: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
int64_t: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
uint64_t: debug_print_printf_specifier(xstr, (void *)xp, TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__}))),\
default: DEBUG_PRINT_CUSTOM_TYPE(xstr, xp, __VA_ARGS__))

#define DEBUG_PRINT_CUSTOM_TYPE(xstr, xp,...) \
debug_print_custom_to_debug_string(xstr, xp, &((dsc_func_ptr){GET_CREATE_DEBUG_STRING_FUNC(xp)}), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__,\
debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options){__VA_ARGS__})))



#define GET_CREATE_DEBUG_STRING_FUNC(x) _Generic((x), \
debug_print_options *: debug_print_options_to_debug_string, \
debug_print_group_options *: debug_print_group_options_to_debug_string, \
default: print_not_valid_type_for_debug_print)
```

I need a pointer to `x` in `DEBUG_PRINT` which may be a variable or an expression. To support expressions I assign it to a temporary and then take the address of that. I could emulate `__typeof__` with `_Generic` for a limited set of types but then users would need to add lines for custom types in 2 places. Is there any other way to do this? I'd be ok with only supporting the latest Microsoft C compiler.

Comment: MSVC10+ has `decltype`. Not sure if that's accessible from C code.

Comment: MSVC doesn't implement either `_Generic` or `_Pragma`. If you have/want to use Visual Studio, then use `clang-cl` or C++ for generic programming.

Comment: _Pragma is just to suppress warnings, also MSVC supports __pragma which is similar(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx)

Comment: You could *possibly* use the DbgHelp api to get something similar.  The odds that you won't have to modify hundreds or thousands of these macro invocations are not fantastic.

Comment: Which part of DbgHelp? Do any of the functions find the types of expressions at run time or debug time?

Comment: @RomanA.Taycher There is no such feature in standard C. Locking yourself into MSVC++ C is unwise; you'll only end up disappointed in a few years time when the alternative you find is unsupported and you're forced to look for yet another alternative. Perhaps you'll be more interested in a language that actually has this feature, such as Javascript?

Comment: I'm writing a small header library to make printf debugging easier. I already use gcc/llvm extension (__type__) and I want to make also work on msvc. I might be able to make it work with the standard by repeating myself and worse forcing the user to repeat themselves if they modify they want to add types(since I can't find a way to extend _Generic without modifying source code) but it would still be c11 which wouldn't be too many useful compilers vs just gcc/llvm/maybe msvc.

Comment: Why do you need pointer? You immediately convert it back into value.

Comment: There is no non pointer void/Any type, you can't pass an object of unknown size to a function by value. The only alternative I can think of is to generate generic functions for each type aka sglib.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a recent version of MSVC, it supports the new C standards, so you can use `_Generic` on it.

Otherwise, for old versions, it depends on how you are compiling your code. If you are actually using the C mode of Visual Studio (i.e. `/Tc` or compiling a file with `.c` extension, which implies `/Tc`), and you cannot use the C++ mode (e.g. the code is in a header), then you are out of luck since MSVC does not support C11 (and therefore you cannot even use `_Generic` to emulate it).

However, if you are compiling in C++ mode (or you can take that luxury), then you can take advantage of `decltype` as @MooingDuck suggested (in recent versions of Visual Studio, e.g. 2017):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
#    define TEMPORARY(x) decltype((x) + 0) _x = (x);
#else
#    define TEMPORARY(x) __typeof__((x) + 0) _x = (x);
#endif

#define DEBUG_PRINT(x) \
    do { \
        TEMPORARY(x); \
        printf("%s = %p\n", #x, &_x); \
    } while(0)

void f()
{
    int y = 100;
    DEBUG_PRINT(123);
    DEBUG_PRINT(y + 123);
}
```

Take a look at the generated code for gcc 7.3 (`-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra`) and MSVC 2017 (`/std:c++14 /W4`), which both seem fine and equivalent: https://godbolt.org/g/sdWAv7

Comment: "...since it does not support C11"? What's the importance of supporting or not supporting C11 in this context? What solution for the OP's problem exists in C11?

Comment: @AnT: IIRC, I was talking about OP's suggested solution using `_Generic` to emulate it. I have added a sentence to clarify.

Comment: For future readers, VS 2019 version `16.8.3` supports both `C11` and `C17` (this includes `_Generic`).

Comment: @WBuck True! The VS team wants to support the new standards now. I will update the answer.

Comment: They *partially* support C11/C17. There are still some egregious omissions (namely `stdatomic.h`, `threads.h`, variable length arrays, the `_Complex` type, the `_Pragma` operator (despite having a `__pragma` operator already?!?), `stdalign.h`, and others I'm sure I'm forgetting --- Yes, I know those things were changed to being *optional*, but they're trivial to implement for a company like Microsoft).

Answer (score -5):

```
char: debug_print_printf_specifier("x"//z.str, (void *)xp, \ 
TYPE_PTR_TO_PRINTF_SPECIFIER(xp), __FILE__, __LINE__, _my_func__, \ 
debug_print_options_apply_group_options(&((debug_print_options{__VA_ARGS__}))),\
z=ptr.x
//just create a ptr z for x... :D
```

simple as that .. ;)

Comment: Please include more elaborative description of the solution and format the code.